# How to export Excel range to an image, used as background in iObeya, with specific width, height

Tags: excel, vba, background-image

I need to import a background image to iObeya.
This background is a range from an Excel sheet.

Here is the code used to export.

```vb
Sub RangeToPicture(rPrt as Range, fileName As String)
    Dim chtObj As ChartObject
    On Error Resume Next
    rPrt.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap
    Set chtObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(1, 1, rPrt.Width, rPrt.Height)
    On Error GoTo 0
    chtObj.Activate
    ActiveChart.Paste
    ActiveChart.Export fileName
    chtObj.Delete
End Sub
```

The final image width an height is not always the same.

I added some `Debug.Print`s in Excel to debug this:

```
chtObj.Width = 1398,90002441406
chtObj.Height = 468
> ratio = **2,98**9102616

ActiveChart.Width = 1398,9
ActiveChart.Height = 468
> ratio = **2,98**9102564
```

I tried to convert points to pixels, to understand what is happening but it does not work as I expected.

```
ActiveWindow.PointsToScreenPixelsX(ActiveChart.Shapes(1).Width) = 2246
ActiveWindow.PointsToScreenPixelsY(ActiveChart.Shapes(1).Height) = 269
```

png file:
From my latop screen: Width = 9329  Height = 3123 > ratio = **2,98**7191803

From my external screen : Width = 3732 , Height = 1249 > ratio = **2,98**7990392

From an other computer: Width = 3487, Height = 1249 > ratio = **2,79**1833467 *<<< this is the file used in iObeya*

Width and height varies, and from one computer to an other one the ratio varies as well.

How is it possible to get always the same dimensions?

Width an Height in Excel are points not pixels.
I understood that Zoom can be an issue, the screen ratio and definition are also an issue, but there is certainly other issues I do not think of.

I have to do the export with a fixed width and height, or with a fixed ratio.